# change variable name based on target and export target specific variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build release and debug version of my binary. `all` is building the release, which is working alright. I would like to add a `make debug` to change my binary name and compile with a set of different flags. To do this, I'm using target specific variables in my top Makefile.

```
BINARY=hello

debug: DBG:=1
debug: $(BINARY)+=_debug
export DBG

debug: bin/$(BINARY).bin
all: bin/$(BINARY).bin
```

`$(BINARY).bin` has its own set of rules which work fine for the release part, as it was the only target I had before. After adding the debug target, I was hoping,

- The `DBG` variable gets exported, so that my recursive Makefile can pick it up to change compilation flags, which I think is working
- The binary name changes, appending `_debug` which it is not. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

EDIT:

Adding some more information about how my `bin` target is built. My `bin/$(BINARY).bin` target depends on some .img and other .bin files whose target name I would also like to change based on whether I am building release or debug.

```
bin/$(BINARY).bin: bin/$(SOME_IMAGE).img bin/$(BINARY_1).bin 
                  .....

bin/$(SOME_IMAGE).img: bin/$(BINARY_2).bin
                     ......

bin/$(BINARY_1).bin: bin/$(BINARY_1).hex
                   ......

bin/$(BINARY_1).hex:
                   $(MAKE) -C some-dir

bin/$(BINARY_2).bin: bin/$(BINARY_2).hex
                   ......

bin/$(BINARY_2).hex:
                   $(MAKE) -C some-other-dir
```

to build debug, I am trying:

```
debug: export DBG:=1
debug: $(BINARY)+=_debug
debug: $(SOME_IMG)+=_debug
debug: $(BINARY_1)+=_debug
debug: $(BINARY_2)+=_debug
```

but that isn't doing the trick

Comment: are you aware that writing recursive Makefiles is a very bad idea, only properly used in some special cases?

Comment: I have read about that. I will try to modify my build system, but in this case my target specific variable is not changing the variable name which might be something other than a problem related with recursive make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly how I would approach the problem:

```
BINARY=hello

all: bin/$(BINARY).bin

debug: DBG:=1
debug: bin/$(BINARY)_debug.bin

bin/$(BINARY).bin bin/$(BINARY)_debug.bin:
    @echo building $@, flag is $(DBG)
```

I am not sure that this solves your whole problem-- I couldn't parse your first bullet point. If it doesn't, perhaps you could edit your question to add a complete example.

Comment: So the idea with this would be that when debug is called, the first target will not exist and hello_debug.bin will be made? This approach will have me add an additional target  for debug, which I was hoping to avoid by having the name of the variable BINARY changed so that it reflects wherever it is used in the Makefile

Comment: @rookie: I don't see the advantage in changing the value of `BINARY` over having an explicitly different target name.

Comment: I added some more information about how my binary targt is being built. In short it depends on a bunch of other binaries whose names i would also like to change when building in debug mode. How can I use the method you suggested when there are multiple dependencies whose name I would like to change, as in the first line of my EDIT . Wouldn't that also litter my Makefile with release and debug targets? I thought using the target specific variable method would be a cleaner way of replacing all related target names.

Answer (score 1):

The value of target-specific variable is available only within the target's recipe, not for the target's prerequisites. When you create the target-specific variable by incrementing the global variable, you now have *two* variables, one global, one target-specific.  Yes you can export target-specific variable to prerequisites in a submake, with an export attribute. (All of this comes from the manual, section on target-specific variables.).

Prerequisites are evaluated at parse-time, from the current values of global variables (not from target-specific ones).

So, this is what you probably want.  You seem to prefer trial-and-error, to actually RTFM.  IMHO, you should really RTFM more, not guess functionality.

```
BINARY:=hello

all: bin/$(BINARY).bin

BINARY := $(BINARY)_debug

debug: export DBG:=1

debug: bin/$(BINARY).bin
```

If this "does not work", here is how you post questions on Stack Overflow.

1. You have a programming goal in mind and you write some code and it does not work the way you expect.
2. You make the code smaller and smaller to search for the cause of the problem.
3. If you have the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem, and you still don't understand why your code does not work, then you post the complete minimal code in your question, and all details of your expectation, and your results different than the expectation.

Comment: If I go this way ,  I would need to duplicate my recipe for `all` and `debug` right. I did edit my question to add more context to what I was trying to achieve. Since I have dependencies whose names I'd also like to change, this becomes more complicated, I guess. Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: @rookie then follow steps 2 and 3 I listed for you.  State your expectations precisely and post the minimal complete example that does not meet your expectations.

Comment: I posted a clear question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346580/makefile-for-release-and-debug-targets

Comment: @rookie  no I can't go to another question...,   I keep the same number of questions answered as asked, I don't have time to answer more

Comment: @rookie all right fine, let me get one more answer for the future, especially that you did not accept the answer that is there already