# Makefile for release and debug targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build a Makefile that can build both release and debug targets by specifying a target rather than a variable (such as `make debug=1`, not great) I have a condensed simplified example here that emulates what I am trying to achieve:

```
ifdef debug
    BINARY=my_binary_debug
    MODULE_1_BIN=abc_debug
    MODULE_2_BIN=xyz_debug
    export DBG=1
else
    BINARY=my_binary
    MODULE_1_BIN=abc
    MODULE_2_BIN=xyz
endif

FLAG=something

.PHONY: all debug clean

all: bin/$(BINARY).bin

bin/$(BINARY).bin: module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN).bin module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN).bin
    cat module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN).bin $(FLAG) module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN).bin > $@

module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN).bin:
    $(MAKE) -C module_1

module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN).bin:
    $(MAKE) -C module_2


clean:
    rm bin/*.bin
    $(MAKE) -C module_1 clean
    $(MAKE) -C module_2 clean
```

This example would have me use `make debug=1` but I don't really like it and feel this implementation could be better. One way is to use target specific variables , but I am not entirely sure how to use them when the dependencies also need to change their names when a debug target is built. Something like:

```
debug: export DBG:=1
debug: bin/$(BINARY)_debug.bin
debug: module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN)_debug.bin
debug: module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN)_debug.bin

bin/$(BINARY).bin bin/$(BINARY)_debug.bin: module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN).bin module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN).bin
        cat module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN).bin module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN).bin > $@
```

Here the target will work alright as the `bin/$(BINARY).bin` target wont need to be built when `debug` is being built.But I am not sure how to handle the dependencies `module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN).bin` and  `module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN).bin` in the recipe when building `debug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A previous version of this answer tried to use target-specific variables, but they are of limited use, because they are used in recipes, but are ignored when it comes to specifying targets and prerequisites.

Implicit rules make use of *patterns,* but capturing both `my_binary` and `my_binary_debug` with the implicit target `my_binary%` doesn’t work, because patterns don’t match the empty string.

In this case however, implicit rules work, because all your targets and dependencies have the common ending `.bin`, which is nonempty. The string that matches `%` is avalaible in the automatic variable `$*`.
So this is my solution:

```
.PHONY: all debug clean

FLAG=something 

# Maybe still needed by subdirectory makefiles
debug: export DBG:=1

all: bin/my_binary.bin
debug: bin/my_binary_debug.bin

# % will match both ".bin" and "_debug.bin"
# It won’t match the empty string.
bin/my_binary%: module_1/abc% module_2/xyz%
    cat module_1/abc$* $(FLAG) module_2/xyz$* > $@

# Maybe, by specifying the target in the sub-make commandline,
# you can get rid of the DBG variable altogether.
module_1/abc%:
    $(MAKE) -C module_1 $@

module_2/xyz%:
    $(MAKE) -C module_2 $@

clean:
    rm bin/*.bin
    $(MAKE) -C module_1 clean
    $(MAKE) -C module_2 clean
```

If the recipe to build `bin/my_binary.bin` can be rewritten with all modules one after another and `$(FLAG)` at the beginning, some more semplifications are possible:

```
.PHONY: all debug clean

MODULES = module_1/abc module_2/xyz
FLAG    = something 

# Maybe still needed by subdirectory makefiles
debug: export DBG:=1

all: bin/my_binary.bin
debug: bin/my_binary_debug.bin

bin/my_binary%: $(addsuffix %,$(MODULES))
    cat $(FLAG) $^ > $@

module_1/abc%:
    $(MAKE) -C module_1 $@

module_2/xyz%:
    $(MAKE) -C module_2 $@

clean:
    rm bin/*.bin
    for m in $(MODULES); do $(MAKE) -C $$(dirname $$m) clean; done
```

Comment: That looks very clean! But BINARY doesn't seem to be taking the value my_binary_debug when I run `make debug`. I change the value of the the sub-binaries based on the DBG using a simple `ifdef` in their resp Makefiles, so those two guys change their value. I added a simple echo like `@echo Building $@ : $<` under the `all debug` target and I see `Building debug : bin/my_binary.bin` when I run `make debug`

Comment: Oh my, you are right. _Target-specific variables are only available within the context of a target’s recipe_ and not in targets and prerequisites... I am going to work out another solution...

Comment: Dario: That's a rollover from an earlier question I posted that Mark is referring to. @Mark: Will make a better effort going forward. Thanks!

Comment: @Dario: Thank you for taking your time to help me with this

Comment: @Dario sorry... I should have posted as a comment to question

Answer (score 1):

As I said before, you cannot use target-specific variables in prerequisites for that target, only in recipes for that target and recursive prerequisites.  I think the best you can do, according to what you want, is this:

```
RELEASE_SUFFIX:=#
DEBUG_SUFFIX:=_debug

BINARY:=my_binary
MODULE_1_BIN:=abc
MODULE_2_BIN:=xyz

FLAG=-u

.PHONY: all debug

all: bin/$(BINARY).bin

debug: export DBG:=1
debug: BINARY+=$(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
debug: bin/$(BINARY).bin


define rules

bin/$(BINARY)$($(1)): module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN)$($(1)).bin module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN)$($(1)).bin
    cat $(FLAG) $$^ > $$@

module_1/$(MODULE_1_BIN)$($(1)).bin:
    $(MAKE) -C $$(@D)

module_2/$(MODULE_2_BIN)$($(1)).bin:
    $(MAKE) -C $$(@D)

endef


$(foreach suffix, RELEASE_SUFFIX DEBUG_SUFFIX, $(eval $(call rules,$(suffix))))
```

Comment: @rookie or, as Dario posted, use implicit rules - that's simpler to understand than my method using `eval`.

Comment: `#` is just a comment. I like to put comments after meaningful white-space, or lack thereof. It's just my habit.  OK, it is more apparent in something like `FOO:=bar #` now `FOO` has empty space at the end, which without the comment, would be hard to see.

Comment: OK, I see. Nice trick anyway. I see your point in using the comment delimiter to be sure a variable is empty.

Comment: @Dario otherwise, in theory, the value could be some empty spaces, and you would not see the difference.  Here in fact, the whole reason why I had to add a level of indirection, is because he wants empty suffix, and there is no way to iterate over empty value with `foreach` - you have to go down to variable names if one of them has an empty value.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the answer, it's an interesting approach!

Comment: @rookie there is nothing interesting about it... it's standard, I don't like implicit rules too much, they are simple OK, but I prefer `eval` in many situations.